# Flight from Melbourne to Heathrow on 17 April 2020

Tags: tickets

Cost of a Qatar flight from Melbourne Australia to London Heathrow on 17/04/2020, booked on 02/04/202

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there are many different kinds of ticket, and the price of each ticket type varies according to numerous factors. Even if the question included all relevant information the airline uses to decide how much it will charge you, it's extremely unlikely anybody could give you an accurate answer a year and a half after the fact.

Comment: Yvonne, this is not twitter. You can use full sentences and punctuation. And you could tell us what research you have already done yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere between $500 and $12000 depending on fare class and ticket type.